Probability of socks matched on 3rd day
A person takes socks out of his drawer that contains 6 pairs of socks, where each pair has a distinct colour. He draws out 2 socks per day without replacement. Find the probability that the third day he takes out socks is the first day he obtained a matching pair. round the answewr to the nearest thousandth.
My logic is to find the probability of this:
P(no matching pair on first day, no matching pair on second day, first matching pair on third day) = P(no matching pair on first day) * P(no matching pair on second day) * P(first matching pair on third day)
Total number cases where no pairs match is to do with choosing different colours of socks; hence, total should be $\binom{6}{2}\times 2 \times 2$ and the number of ways to choose 2 socks is $\binom{12}{2}$
So, P(no matching pair on first day) = $\frac{10}{11}$
For getting same pair of socks, we can choose only one colour, which can be done in $\binom{6}{1}$ ways.
So, P(first matching pair on third day) = $\frac{1}{11}$
The final answer would be $\frac{10}{11}\times \frac{10}{11} \times \frac{1}{11} = 0.075$.
Does this process looks okay?

You've been on the site for $7$ years...why refuse to format?  Why not add context?  As In, what makes you believe the answer you wrote is incorrect?

Not at all clear how you got from your first evaluation to your second.

At a glance, it seems that cases matter.  If you draw $(A,B)$ first and $(A,B)$ second, that seems different than drawing $(A,B)$ first and $(C,D)$ second, no?  Or $(A,B)$ first and $(A,C)$ second.

Without agreeing or disagreeing with your answer, I do note that $\frac{1}{11}\approx .091$, but $\frac{10}{11}\times \frac{10}{11}\times\frac{1}{11}$ has a different value.

@paw88789 you are right; my answer is approx. 0.075

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

This isn't, and as far as I can see never has been, tagged solution-verification. It's just a perfectly normal case of "here's a question I'm not sure about and, for context, here's my attempt at it".

@BillDubuque This is a tricky issue.  Your reaction is reasonable, because the OP (i.e. original poster) is providing what they regard as a complete line of analysis to the problem, and then asking whether each step is valid.  Despite this, because of the situation's subtlety, I think that the viewpoint of Especially Lime should prevail here.  Clearly, the OP doesn't really know what their doing, is showing their attempt, and then asking: How should the problem be attacked ?  That is, I don't think that the OP had any confidence in their own analysis.

@user2661923 The only question asked by the OP is  "does this process look okay?", so it is an SV.

@BillDubuque Superficially yes.  However, you can not expect the OP to understand the nuances of allowing an attempt, but rejecting an s-v question.  It is clear that the OP didn't really know what they were doing.  So, I don't think that the OP should be penalized for their unfortunate choice of words.  I understand resisting sv questions.  However, I think that a balance should be struck based on what is actually happening in the situation.  The OP's approach was so mistaken that they could not possibly have been confident of their approach.

@user2661923 SV/PSQ closures often prove more efficient ways to close dupes. This is surely a dupe too, but it seems there are not many users in the above tags interested in organizing the site.

@BillDubuque That is a very good point.  I am definitely biased against giving priority to maintaining a high quality reservoir of questions versus educating, and my bias generally comes out, such as in this situation.  As your last comment indicates, others share the bias, but have opted, as I have, for some sort of peaceful co-existence.  From my viewpoint, this means trying to strike a balance between my bias, and the explicitly stated priority of the forum.  As clear evidence, the widespread use of (? partial)hint-comments is another symptom of the widespread balance-seeking.

@user2661923 I don't disagree that the boundaries can be quite fuzzy on such subjective matters.

I believe the correct probability is $\frac{50}{693}$.
Here is my reasoning. First of all, I am going to conceptualize the process as laying out $6$ random socks in a row without looking. Then I will
(i) Look only at socks $5$ and $6$ in the row and check if they match. If they do match, I will continue:
(ii) Look only at socks $1$ and $2$ in the row and check if they don't match. If they don't match, I will continue:
(iii) Look at socks $3$ and $4$ in the row and check if they don't match.
For (i), the probability of a match is $\frac{1}{11}$.
For (ii), the conditional probability of a non-match (given match in step (i)) is $\frac{8}{9}$ (since there are $5$ matched pairs at this stage).
For (iii), the conditional probability of a non-match in step (iii) (given match in step (i) and non-match in step (ii)) is $1-\frac68\cdot \frac17=\frac{25}{28}$.
[The reasoning here is to use the complement of a match at this stage. There are currently $3$ pairs of socks and $2$ odd socks. So for a match, we need to get a sock from one of the $3$ pairs, followed by its mate.]
Putting this all together, using notation $M_3$ for match on day $3$ and $U_1$ and $U_2$ for unmatched on days $1$ and $2$ respectively, we have:
$${\rm Pr}(M_3 \cap U_1 \cap U_2)=\frac{1}{11}\cdot \frac89 \cdot \frac{25}{28}=\frac{50}{693}$$
Two final notes: (1) A Python simulation seemed quite consistent with this result. And (ii), regarding the work shown in the original question, I think there were issues with assuming too much independence of sock draws, with the appropriate conditional probabilities not being taken into account.

How can you look at socks 5 & 6 first ? Aren't you supposed to proceed serially from 1 onwards ? When I do that, I get a much lower answer ! You might like to simulate serially and see . Of course, the question is now closed, but it piques my interest ! Good day !

@trueblueanil I structured my answer with the laying out of the $6$ socks in order, blind before looking at any of the $6$ socks. That doesn't affect the probabilities involved. Then I chose an order to observe the socks that would make the probabilities easier to compute (less casework). By the way, in order to double check, I went further with Python and actually did a non-simulated solution where every possibility was checked. Answer of $\frac{50}{693}$ was confirmed. ($48000$ of $665280$ cases were favorable.)

I agree that in the order you have chosen, your result is absolutely correct. But I am not at all sure that in drawing socks, you can interchange the order of draws to avoid cases. Did you check for that ? At the second draw, there are three cases (a) no further pair is broken (b) one more pair is broken (c) two more pairs are broken.  Incidentally, idk why the question was closed in such a tearing hurry !

@trueblueanil Suppose you had $3$ blue balls and $5$ red balls in a bag. You draw out two balls, one after the other, without replacement. What is the probability that the second ball drawn is red?

I am Ok with shoes, but seem to get socked by socks ! $;;$ :)

The answer is correct. FYI, seeing "He draws out 2 socks per day without replacement", I thought he was picking two socks without replacement, then putting those back, and then again in next day he is picking without replacement. Hence, I assumed too much independence. Such a silly misunderstanding.

@trueblueanil If you lay out the socks in advance (as I suggested in my answer), it shouldn't matter what order you look at the pairs. For instance you might not ever look at the socks you wear, but your coworker might say (on the third day), "My goodness, you finally managed to wear a pair of matching socks--first time in three days."

Your answer is much more elegant than my rehabilitation-answer, which confirms your $~\dfrac{50}{693}~$ computation.

I agree with the analysis in the answer of paw88789 and I think that their response is more elegant than the approach that I am going to take.
Basically, I am going to rehabilitate the approach taken by the OP (i.e. original poster).  However, the OP mistakenly ignored a hidden complexity in the problem.
Let

$R_1~$ denote the event that there was no match on the 1st day.

$R_2~$ denote the event that there was no match on the 2nd day.

$R_3~$ denote the event that there was a match on the 3rd day.


Then, the overall approach of
$$p( ~R_1 ~) \times p( ~R_2 ~| ~R_1 ~) \times p( ~R_3 ~| ~R_1, ~R_2 ~) \tag1 $$
is valid.
Further, as the OP indicated, $~p( ~R_1 ~) = \dfrac{10}{11}.$
The difficulty is that the event $~( ~R_2 ~| ~R_1 ~)~$ can happen in three different ways.  Further, the manner in which the event $~( ~R_2 ~| ~R_1 ~)~$ occurs directly affects the computation of $~p( ~R_3 ~| ~R_1, ~R_2 ~).$

Labeling the $~6~$ pairs of socks as $~A_1, ~A_2, ~B_1, ~B_2, ~\cdots, ~F_1, ~F_2,~$ you can reserve the factor, of $~p( ~R_1 ~) = \dfrac{10}{11},~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that on the first day, the specific socks of $~[ ~A_1 ~:: ~B_1 ~]~$ were chosen.
Consider the following three (mutually exclusive) possible ways that the event $~( ~R_2 ~| ~R_1 ~)~$ can occur.

1st Possibility: 
Day 2 choice $~= [ ~A_2 ~:: ~B_2 ~].$ 
The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{1}{45}.$ 
If this does happen, then the remaining socks will be 
$\{ ~C_1, ~C_2, ~D_1, ~D_2, ~E_1, ~E_2, ~F_1, ~F_2 ~\}.$ 
So, in this scenario,
$~\displaystyle p( ~R_3 ~| ~R_1, ~R_2 ~) = \frac{4}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{4}{28}.~$ 
Therefore, the computation that should be assigned to this bullet point is $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{45} \times \frac{4}{28}.$ 

2nd Possibility: 
Day 2 choice is $~1~$ sock from $~\{ ~A_2, ~B_2 ~\},~$ and $~1~$ sock from $~\{ ~C_1, ~C_2, ~\cdots, ~F_1, ~F_2 ~\}.$ 
The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{2}{1} ~\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{16}{45}.$ 
If this does happen, you can assume, without loss of generality, that the Day 2 choice $~= [ ~A_2 ~:: ~C_1 ~].$ 
If this does happen, then the remaining socks will be 
$\{ ~B_2, ~C_2, ~D_1, ~D_2, ~E_1, ~E_2, ~F_1, ~F_2 ~\}.$ 
So, in this scenario,
$~\displaystyle p( ~R_3 ~| ~R_1, ~R_2 ~) = \frac{3}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{3}{28}.~$ 
Therefore, the computation that should be assigned to this bullet point is $~\displaystyle \frac{16}{45} \times \frac{3}{28}.$ 

3rd Possibility: 
Day 3 choice is $~2~$ unmatching socks from $~\{ ~C_1, ~C_2, ~\cdots, ~F_1, ~F_2 ~\}.$ 
The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{8}{2} - 4}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{24}{45}.$ 
If this does happen, you can assume, without loss of generality, that the Day 2 choice $~= [ ~C_1 ~:: ~D_1 ~].$ 
If this does happen, then the remaining socks will be 
$\{ ~A_2, B_2, ~C_2, ~D_2, ~E_1, ~E_2, ~F_1, ~F_2 ~\}.$ 
So, in this scenario,
$~\displaystyle p( ~R_3 ~| ~R_1, ~R_2 ~) = \frac{2}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{2}{28}.~$ 
Therefore, the computation that should be assigned to this bullet point is $~\displaystyle \frac{24}{45} \times \frac{2}{28}.$ 



Therefore, the (overall) final computation is
$$\frac{10}{11} \times \left\{ ~ 
\left[ ~\frac{1}{45} \times \frac{4}{28} ~\right] 
+ \left[ ~\frac{16}{45} \times \frac{3}{28} ~\right]
+ \left[ ~\frac{24}{45} \times \frac{2}{28} ~\right]
~\right\} $$
$$= \frac{10}{11} \times \frac{1}{45 \times 28} \times ( ~4 + 48 + 48 ~)$$
$$= \frac{10 \times 100}{11 \times 45 \times 28} = \frac{100}{11 \times 9 \times 14} = \frac{100}{1386} = \frac{50}{693}.$$

Users had previously downvoted due to lack of explanation in my approach, which is wrong from what I can see now, but 4 users had already tried to close this thread, even though I had updated the explanation part since then, not sure why.
